# How to connect to IBM MQ deployed to OpenShift?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, openshift, ibm-mq

I have a container with IBM MQ (Docker image `ibmcom/mq/9.2.2.0-r1`) exposing two ports (9443 - admin, 1414 - application).

All required setup in OpenShift is done (Pod, Service, Routes).

There are two routes, one for each port.

- https://route-admin.my.domain
- https://route-app.my.domain

pointing to the ports accordingly (external ports are default http=80, https=443).

Admin console is accessible through the first route, hence, MQ is up and running.

I tried to connect as a client (JMS 2.0, `com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.2.2.0`) using standard approach:

```
  var fctFactory = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
  var conFactory = fctFactory.createConnectionFactory();

  // ... other props

  conFactory.setObjectProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "route-app.my.domain");
  conFactory.setObjectProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 443);
```

and failed to connect. Also tried to redefine route as HTTP and use port 80, and again without success.

If it helps let's assume we use the latest version of MQ Explorer as a client.

Each time the same connection error appears:

```
...
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: 
           IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2009' ('MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN').
... 
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: 
           CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'route-app.my.domain(443)' rejected.
           [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: 
            Error on receive from host 'route-app.my.domain/10.227.248.2:443 (route-app.my.domain)'.
           [1=-1,2=ffffffff,3=route-app.my.domain/10.227.248.2:443 (route-app.my.domain),4=TCP]],
            3=route-app.my.domain(443),5=RemoteConnection.receiveTSH]
...
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2009;AMQ9208: 
           Error on receive from host 'route-app.my.domain/10.227.248.2:443
```

Maybe, this [article](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mq-connection-terminating-error-code-2009) could give some hints about error code 2009, but still not sure what exactly affects connection errors from the OpenShift side.

Previously, I always connected to IBM MQ specifying a port value explicitly, but here is a bit different situation.
**How to connect to IBM MQ in OpenShift cluster through TCP?**

---

Configurations in OpenShift are as follows:

---

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ibm-mq
  labels:
    app: ibm-mq
spec:
  containers:
    - resources:
        limits:
          cpu: '1'
          memory: 600Mi
        requests:
          cpu: '1'
          memory: 600Mi
      name: ibm-mq
      ports:
        - containerPort: 1414
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9443
          protocol: TCP
  containerStatuses:
      image: 'nexus-ci/docker-lib/ibm_mq:latest'

---
   
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ibm-mq
spec:
  ports:
    - name: admin
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9443
      targetPort: 9443
    - name: application
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1414
      targetPort: 1414
  selector:
    app: ibm-mq

---

kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ibm-mq-admin
spec:
  host: ibm-mq-admin.my-domain.com
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: ibm-mq
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: admin
  tls:
    termination: passthrough
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: None
  wildcardPolicy: None

---

kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ibm-mq-app
spec:
  host: ibm-mq-app.my-domain.com
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: ibm-mq
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: application
  tls:
    termination: passthrough
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: None
  wildcardPolicy: None

---
```

**UPDATE:** Ended up with creating and deploying to OpenShift a small web-application receiving HTTP requests and interacting with MQ via JMS (put/get text messages), like:

- `POST /queue/{queueName}/send + <body>`;
- `GET /queue/{queueName}/receive`.

It interacts with MQ inside the OpenShift cluster using TCP, and accepts external HTTP connections as a regular web application.
Other solutions seem to take too much efforts, but I accepted one of them as it is theoretically correct and straightforward.

Comment: Which version of the mq client jar files are you using?   TLS routing is based on the SNI sent from the client to openshift.  MQ behavior changed in java over time.   Prior to 9.1 java did not send SNI.  In 9.2 it sent a channel name based SNI.  In 9.2 it allows you to send the host name you are connecting to.

Comment: You mention port 1414 on line one of your question and then never use it again throughout the question. 1414 is the default IBM MQ port to listen on. Have you tried connecting to your hostname and port 1414?

Comment: Does this help - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=containers-connecting-queue-manager-deployed-in-openshift-cluster?

Comment: @MoragHughson 1414 is the port exposed from the container (Pod) and via Service it is passed to Route. Route uses it internally and 1414 is not visible to the outer world. External connections to the Route could go through HTTP (80) or HTTPS(443) and then according to the config (incl. port) the Route redirects traffic to the Service.

Comment: @JoshMc I use Java 11 and client com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.2.0.2; Server is a standard Docker image `ibmcom/mq/9.2.2.0-r1`. Could you elaborate in an answer on how to implement sending host name to SNI?

Comment: @Shashi, I see phrase "You must enable TLS on your IBM MQ queue manager and client application" and no links or instructions after that. Is it obvious how to do that?

Comment: Yes, both QM and Client application must be TLS enabled. Without that you will not be able to connect. This article - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mft-cloud/blob/mftubi/docs/connectmqexplorer.md I wrote describes steps for connecting MQExplorer to a Queue manager running in OpenShift. I think this gives you an idea. MQExplorer is a Java application.

Comment: My article is based on this - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=manager-example-configuring-tls

Comment: MQ offers a REST api a well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to fully understand your setup, but`"Routes"`only route HTTP traffic (On ports 80 or 443 onyl), not TCP traffic.
If you want to access your MQ server from outside the cluster, there are a few solutions, one is to create a service of type: `"NodePort"`

Doc: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/networking/configuring_ingress_cluster_traffic/configuring-ingress-cluster-traffic-nodeport.html

Your Service is not a NodePort Service. In your case, it should be something like

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ibm-mq
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 1414
      targetPort: 1414
      nodePort: 30001
  selector:
    app: ibm-mq
```

Then access from outside with anyname.<cluster domaine>:30001
And delete the useless corresponding route. As said before, I assumed you read in the doc I pointed to you that says that route only route HTTP traffic on port 80 or 443.

Doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot create a service with NodePort. `Error "Forbidden: may not be used when 'type' is 'ClusterIP'" for field "spec.ports[1].nodePort".`. Got this even when "type" is not set. Not sure why does it happen.

Comment: Updated the question with YAML configs of (Pod, Service, 2 Routes).

Comment: Actually, I believe your answer is fully correct. Looks like it is not possible to access the queue from outside the container. I'll have to install some ibmmq client (with web interface) to OpenShift and work through it.

Comment: Your service is not a NopePort Service. It must have a spec.type: NodePort. Check kubernetes doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport. And you do not need the routes....

Answer (score 0):

The following Java system property will be read by IBM MQ classes for JMS at 9.2.1 and higher to tell it to set the SNI header to the hostname of the remote system when initiating a TLS connection:

```java
com.ibm.mq.cfg.SSL.OutboundSNI=HOSTNAME
```

---

To set this programmatically just use the `System.setProperty` method for example:

```java
System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.SSL.OutboundSNI","HOSTNAME");
```

---

**NOTE:** the string `HOSTNAME` is literal and not meant to be replaced by a actual hostname.

---

If you can not move to a `com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar` from 9.2.1 or later,  then in 9.2.0.0 and later you could instead use `com.ibm.mq.cfg.SSL.AllowOutboundSNI=NO`, but this is deprecated in 9.2.1 and later.

Comment: I upgraded client to the latest version = 9.2.2.0; and set the property `com.ibm.mq.cfg.SSL.OutboundSNI`, but error is the same. What if we simplify the task. Let's assume we use the latest version of MQ Explorer. It fails to connect with similar error. When I run the same Docker image locally and connect to `localhost:1414` the connection is fine.

Comment: Do you use TLS channels, this is also a requirement.  Shashi provide a good link in the question comments.