# Spring Boot connecting to IBM MQ Cloud

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-cloud, ibm-mq

I'm trying to send a message to a IBM MQ queue from my spring boot service. I could send/receive the message from the IBM MQ installed on my laptop.

However when I replaced the configuration to connect to the IBM MQ Cloud, this is not working

Configuration is as follows:

[image]

getting the following error

[image]

**Note:**

- I could telnet into the host & port
- I tried with the following for Username & Password
- With APIKey & App Name
- My IBM Username & Password

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67926772/how-to-connect-to-ibm-mq-deployed-to-openshift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue:

The connection may be broken for a number of different reasons. The 2009 return code indicates that something prevented a successful connection to the Queue Manager. The most common causes for this are the following are:

1. A firewall that is terminating the connection
2. An IOException that causes the socket to be closed
3. An explicit action to cause the socket to be closed by one end
4. The queue manager is offline
5. The maximum number of channels allowed by the queue manager are open
6. A configuration problem in the Queue Connection Factory (QCF)

Can you please try suggestions from [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mq-connection-terminating-error-code-2009)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the most common reason for Error Code 2009: MQRC_CONECTION_BROKEN is that your JMS client opens up multiple connections to the queue and they remain unclosed even though they're not being used. You then eventually run out of channels. You can increase the channel size to more than double of what is required.

**Check your FFST log file generated by IBM MQ classes for JMS. It gives you detailed info on connections/errors:**

[First Failure Support Technology ( FFST ) files](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=ffst-mq-classes-jms)